# How to edit code in VS code on private server

Tags: visual-studio-code, amazon-ec2, ssh

I want to edit code on server over VS code ssh. With public access server it works fine. I just connect to IP over ssh with my key by VS Code ssh extension. But now I want to edit code on private server that can be accessed over public one.

Over terminal connection process look like:

```
> ssh -i key user@10.445.322.12 
connected to public server
> ssh -i key user@172.43.65.11 
connected to private server
```

So how I can achieve that? This two servers hosted on EC2 Amazon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SSH's feature [ProxyJump](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/ssh-proxy-bastion-proxyjump) to achieve this.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and run command `Remote-SSH: Open SSH Configuration File`:

[image: Open SSH Configuration File]

Insert both hosts and add the `ProxyJump` directive to your private server:

```
Host PublicServer
  HostName 10.445.322.12
  User user

Host PrivateServer
  HostName 172.43.65.11
  User user
  ProxyJump PublicServer
```

Afterwards you should be able to connect to `PrivateServer` directly from VS Code.